# jQuery Mobile - AJAX JSON

Tags: json, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I am having trouble figuring out why jQuery Mobile will not handle my json return in an AJAX call.  It works perfectly fine in any web browser but not on my mobile phone (android).  The script just hangs, it will not even choose either of the if statement options in the success function.

```
$('#loginSubmit').click(function() {
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); 
     $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "/include/login.php",
                  data: $('#loginForm').serialize(),
                  cache: false,
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function (json) {
                        if(json && json.error != '') {
                            //alert(json.error);
                            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();                              
                        } else {
                            $.mobile.changePage('/mobile/cp/', { transition: "slide" });
                            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                        }
                  }
                });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: I presume this code executes after the DOM is parsed? (i.e., you use $(document).ready() or $())

Comment: I have tried both.  I have even tried to bind the mobileinit to the document as well.  I have successfully used all of the $.post, $.get, $.ajax and $.getJSON functions of jQuery on this sample in a browser.  Once I try it on the mobile phone no go with json. The mobile phone will however return datatype:"text" properly

Comment: Have you checked if the ajax post is successful? It sounds to me like it fails somehow. Is the JSON valid for example? http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once with the new beta, when i enabled ajaxLinks. If i then wanted to add code for elements, that were not on my startpage, i could not use

`$(document).ready function`.

I used the

```
$('#page').live('pageshow', function() ...
```

to add my code at pagechange. So my elements i wanted to add the javascript to were currently rendered.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am not having problems submitting the form or disabling the auto JQM ajaxFormsEnabled feature. I am having trouble getting the return json from an ajax call.

Comment: And you're sure, the ajax call is submitted?